# Which update patches should I install for the PC DVD versions of Majesty 2 and its expansions?

Tags: majesty-2

The official [Majesty 2 website](http://www.majesty2.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=80&Itemid=155) and [The Patches Scrolls website](http://www.patches-scrolls.de/majesty2_the_fantasy_kingdom_sim.php#1188) (which is linked as a mirror by the official Majesty 2 website) show different "latest" update patches for Majesty 2.

The official website states that patch 1.1.88 is the latest version and the Patches Scrolls website states that patch 1.4.356.0 is the latest version.

Which is the latest version that I should install for the PC DVD version? Also, do I need to install the patch if I also have the Kingmaker expansion? What about the Battles of Ardania expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wonders, it appears that Majesty 2 has different update versions for each expansion. This means that the latest patch version for Majesty 2 with no expansions is 1.1.88, while 1.4.356.0, is for one of Majesty 2's later expansions.